# Softening suffixes in English

Tags: suffixes, diminutive

In Russian and we have a lot of different **softening suffixes**. Are there any in English? Like how would you rephrase as one word the following: **a lovely chair**, **a most favorite small chair**, **a small lovely chair**, **a chair that is most comfortable**.

I was thinking of using some suffixes like in the word **"starlet"** - one of the meanings of which is **a small star** but the words seem very odd and unnatural then.

- **a lovely chair** - **a chairly**
- **a small lovely chair** - **a chairlette** with **-ette** as a **diminutive (makes something smaller)**
- **a most favorite small chair** - **a chairestetteous**
- **a chair that is most comfortable** - **a chairfyious**

I think many English suffixes can't be used with nouns and change the words to an adjective, verb, adverb or e.t.c.

I looked here https://www.learnthat.org/pages/view/suffix.html#up for the proper suffixes.

Comment: Relevant: [Diminutive forms in English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296694), [How are diminutives formed in recent English words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7399)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just doesn't work in English: the use of such suffixes is very restricted. For instance, your example *starlet* can't mean *small star*: it only means *minor celebrity*. I can't think of any such suffix that could be used after *chair*. Certainly no such word is in the official Scrabble dictionary.

But I am curious -- what are all these derivatives of стул in Russian?

Comment: In Russian it is: стульчик, стульченька, стульчичек, стульчичёнок, стульчишка, стульчёночек, стульчичёночичек, стульчишечка, стулчичёноченька, стульчичёнушек, стульленёночичек, стульчишка and e.t.c They all have degree of emotional significance and size value. Some are more endearing while others are more diminutive. Some are more valuable while others are more beloved.

Comment: @SovereignSun: Thank you! Are all these real? Google finds about half of them. Would anybody ever say стульчичёночичек in real life?

Comment: Very very very rarely, I'd say 0.00001% possibility. But it is still possible. Anyway most of these words can be met in real life but not even a half of them are dictionary words.

Comment: There's "drinky-poo".  And you could say "chairy-wairy" but that's definitely baby talk.

Comment: @johnfeltz That is interesting. Do you have nore examples and info on where to search for such baby words. In Russia babies also say words that don't exust but sound very interesting and unordinary. Some people start using them afterwards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk  section 4.2 covers diminutives

Comment: @JohnFeltz This link you gave is wonderful! I need a list of words that babies use and speak.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I can think of is the diminutive suffix [*-ie*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ie) or *-y*. You may know from affectionate nicknames such as *Billy*, *Mikey*, *Barbie*, *Paulie*, etc., but it is sometimes used with common nouns as well: *deafie*, *Aussie*, *boatie* (remember Boaty McBoatface? Schoolie McSchoolface?). Note that this suffix isn't necessarily endearing, and is often used to belittle the suffixee: *greenie*, *queenie*, *Rhodie*, etc..

A more reliable option is using *nice little __*: *A nice little chair*.

Comment: Yeh, I know perfectly well about using "a nice little", "a beautiful small", "a marvelous tiny" and e.t.c but is there some way we can one-word it?

Comment: Look at the words **"beddie", "kitty", "puppy"** they are both diminutive and endearing I guess. But we can still say it's my **lovely little beddie**.

Comment: @SovereignSun: _beddie_ doesn't work for me, I'm afraid. There is the children's word _beddie-byes_, but no stand-alone word _beddie_. Can you post a link to an example of its use?

Comment: @TonyK https://books.google.ru/books?id=Upm0TkyixDIC&pg=PA400&lpg=PA400&dq=my+beddie&source=bl&ots=DxfRuivo5d&sig=2_0rNphPHW7wWk8dZ0k_eDzgYjQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNyq3tucvQAhXhJ5oKHZG7CJsQ6AEIPDAG#v=onepage&q=my%20beddie&f=false and https://books.google.ru/books?id=1Vxla6GNM2cC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=my+beddie&source=bl&ots=rcN0YSADBL&sig=VZigjJZKBTFYdAdptUfe69HXavU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNyq3tucvQAhXhJ5oKHZG7CJsQ6AEIRTAI#v=onepage&q=my%20beddie&f=false

Comment: @SovereignSun: The first link is a letter by Lotte Lenya, an Austrian. The second is the plea of a drunkard ("Take me to my beddie"). So I would not count either of these as proper English. Interestingly, it seems that _beddie_ does exist, but not as a diminutive of _bed_: it is (Australian?) slang for _bedmate_.

Comment: I don't know if it's an Australian diminutive, but there's a Wikipedia article on  [Diminutives in Australian English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutives_in_Australian_English), which may be germane to this discussion.

Comment: TonyK slang for bedmate I heard that definition but it's slang and that's not exactly what interests me.